# ¿ como identificar que el atributo de un objecto es un tipo clase? C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net

Estoy haciendo un método en c# donde recorro un objeto sacando sus atributos, sus propiedades y a su ves sacando el valor de las propiedades, pero algunos de estos atributos son clases que a su ves contiene mas propiedades, debo acceder a ellos, para esto el método lo estoy haciendo recursivo, el problema es que no se como identificar que estas propiedades son clases, alguna idea???

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta mostrando el código que haz realizado y detalles de cómo reproducir tu escenario. Date una vuelta por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla. Saludos :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes validarlo con el siguiente fragmento de codigo :

```
 Type  myType = typeof(atributoValidar);

 myType.IsClass retorna verdadero o falso
```

Espero te sirva ;)

Comment: Gracias me sirvió mucho

Comment: De nada , para eso estamos, para colaborarnos.